# This SE site is probably the most welcoming of the whole network

Tags: discussion

This is not a question but a subjective opinion I have expressed elsewhere as well.

I am on SE for 12 or so years and I was always disappointed by the toxicity of many main "SE network nodes" (with SO being at the very top).

I discovered SE LaTeX a few years ago by wandering in the Hot Network entries. having used LaTeX in my past life (physics) I was borderline interested.

What really strikes me here is the welcoming atmosphere, the quality of the answers etc. Even basic questions are responded to with kindness.

**Thanks for that.** SE LaTeX has become some kind of psychologically soothing journey.

Comment: I wouldn't like to curb your enthusiasm but it's not always as welcoming as it seems.

Comment: Hear, hear! TeX - LaTeX SE is certainly among the most welcoming SE sites by any measure.

Comment: @CarLaTeX: there are certainly all sorts of cases but the posts I saw always have straightforward, complete answers. Not the "what research have you done?" or "closed because duplicate" (when it is not a duplicate at all). My baseline for comparison is SO (this i san easy target), but also other more specialized sites where one could expect more tolerance. Having gone though low-effort questions a lot, I understand that some are really bad; at the same time, someone with experience in SE who asks a generic question may really be lost and would just need a small poke in the right direction

Comment: Thank you for your kind words.  The members of this community are often in a minority, besieged by others who say that our software is obsolete or irrelevant, and we should be using something more "modern".  Some of our "kindness" is simply born of a desire for self-preservation.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: LaTeX is not in a simple situation. I use it somehow extensively for my PhD thesis (and my wife's as well), in times where Word would suddenly say goodbye and you would be left with a pile of binary files that are not useable. I also appreciated the fact that it is so difficult to change anything that you give up and start to write instead of trying to change your headers :)

Comment: @barbarabeeton (cont'd) I have a son who is in high school and I am trying to make him use LaTex (via Overleaf) for his math assignments. It is really tough, he is willing but I see that the time he spends typing a page is 1/5th of Google Docs. His math is honestly not complex enough so that the built-in equation solutions could not be used.

Comment: Also, because the community regulars are few, we know each other quite well (and many know each other in real life from annual meetings, etc.). This gives another feeling to this community in general.

Comment: Oh, and we got @PauloCereda. Big plus!

Comment: In general, I find the more "technical" an SE is, the less toxic the community is. When you're getting into more "opinion based" SE sites, that's when you tend to get drama flaring up.

Comment: @Crazymoomin: I do not think so. SO, Server Fault are terrible. SE Networking not so much (or crypto). Information Security is not too good because there are plenty of assumptions about the asker. Cooking is fine, worldbuilding too. I think it depends on the ego of the main users of a site.

Comment: @WoJ Server Fault do seem to freeze out people who aren't sysops, I'll admit. I think it's down to what they see as their remit, they see themselves as a SE by professionals, for professionals. Network Engineering OTOH seems more willing to accept amateurs. SO is just so big it really depends on the crowd your question attracts.

Comment: [Re](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8818/this-se-site-is-probably-the-most-welcoming-of-the-whole-network#comment28776_8818) writing math being faster in Google Docs, as with many technical skills of this sort, it's faster to do easy things the streamlined way … but eventually your son will hit something that isn't specifically built into the streamlined flow, and then he'll be glad to have an escape hatch.  I hope he sticks with it!

Comment: @Crazymoomin: I have been a sysadmin for more years than I would like to admit (having contributed a small bit in the Linux kernel in 1994). I sometimes had a specific question and it is always the "have you done your research" - and I really wish to have been able to kindly take the folk by the shoulders, and show him 25 years of work across thousands and thousands of servers :) Anyway :)

Comment: @LSpice: yes, I hope so too. He will have quite a lot of math, but I am not sure if this will be enough for him to switch to LaTeX for good (especially that this is typically homework, so a structure of "Exercise 2 page 45", rather than sections. There is a template for that, I am sure :)

Comment: Doubtless there [is](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8818/this-se-site-is-probably-the-most-welcoming-of-the-whole-network#comment28796_8818), but it could be simple and yet idiosyncratic enough that writing his own macros would be even better than looking for someone else's.  Depending on his mindset, a peek into the programming part of LaTeX might appeal if the ability to typeset math prettily does not!

Comment: @CarLaTeX To a degree I, respectfully, disagree. When I was a new bud on the SE network I asked a question here. My question was closed and then another user contested the closure _for me and got the question reopened_. Many sites I've asked on just VTC and leave me in the dark. I've also talked to one of my siblings, who also has the opinion TeX.SE is the most welcoming on the network. I'm a moderator on another site now, so I understand all the worts on my site. But I don't know what the average asker thinks of the site, because I'm no longer part of that demographic.

Comment: @Peilonrayz: I also think that the nature of the site matters. I use SE for ~12 years, respond to questions where I can, and measure how welcoming a site is through the number of WFTs when reading the answers. There are sites where people just dump verbatim their work/school problems and these sites tend to be harsh. Then there are sites such as Cooking or Android where the questions are more genuine, and the sites follow. If suddenly LaTeX was part of the world school curriculum then the overall interest/quality of questions would I believe drop, and reactions may be harsher.

Comment: @Peilonrayz I'm not talking about the question always answered. The problems are with the site management. Trolls are not (or not quickly) banned; and if you disagree with the "caste", you are more or less ostracized.

Comment: @WoJ Despite being off topic I am interested: Son at high school doing the writing-work of his math assignments on the computer? Is that really common nowadays? I'm a little surprised that things have changed so much, because we were explicitly forbidden to do that 30 years ago. We were required to hand in everything in legible handwriting. The keyword "penmanship" was funneled into our ears ad nauseam. There was additional training where we had to learn what to pay attention to when writing by hand with different colored chalks on a large board for an audience. There were grades for that...

Comment: @UlrichDiez: this is a gray zone. Some teachers explicitly say "handwritten" (which is borderline masochistic if you ask me) but they are in minority. No teacher says "computer only". The vast majority does not care I guess. It is also possible that COVID helped a bit in advertising the digital version. Now for the past: it seems that you are German, I am French and I believe (from discussions with German friends) that the approach to learning/writing is similar. I started primary school in the late 70's and we had calligraphy, and also pressure on colors like you. It was not graded, though.

Comment: @WoJ I see. Nowadays, it is common practice not to demotivate children even more when it comes to using computers. :-) It was annoying in my days to have to hand-write everything again if you wanted to change parts of the text you had already written. So at home I wrote the homework on the computer and, instead of printing it out, read off the computer screen and wrote it down on paper. A niece of mine in Corona times by some teachers still is coerced into photographing handwritten paper and submitting the image electronically, which is moronic in my eyes. Chalk and blackboard...

Comment: @WoJ  was in high school. It was about learning to write and draw by hand on the blackboard in a lecture hall during a presentation.

Comment: @UlrichDiez I used to teach at the university and some of the papers written by hand were torture to read. My son has a wavy microscopic style of writing, so I very much encourage him to use a computer so that his teachers are not driven crazy. He loves paper, though, and likes to write.

Comment: @WoJ I believe you. :-)  Our teachers just did not accept papers where the handwriting was bad according to their opinion. You were graded as if you had not handed in anything at all. Sometimes real tragicomedies took place. :-)  The level and quality of "computerization" at German schools varies widely, as does the media literacy of teachers. Bizarre conditions, as usual.

Comment: @UlrichDiez: this is very interesting. I discussed about school with several people and friends across Germany, Italy, Poland, UK, Belgium and there were all kinds of strange traditions, but the tragicomedy you describe (I guess this is a student trying to explain to the teacher that the writing is "good enough") is something new to me :)

Comment: @WoJ Your assumption is correct. In Germany, we have four years of elementary school and during this time it is decided which type of school to attend after that. If you intended to go to university later, you had to go to Gymnasium=Lycée+Collège(?). 8 or 9 years. The curricula published by the education authorities of the respective federal countries were full of the words "creative" and "playful". In eleventh grade, we had to perform self-choreographed "Indian dances" in music class. In twelfth grade, we had to correctly interpret Dadaist/Surrealist poems in class work, which we ...

Comment: @WoJ ...had previously had to write ourselves as so-called Cadavre exquis in the class collective. In order to learn something sensible I got a guest reader's card for the university library as early as possible. I could write about school for hours: I had to go to the same school where my father was a math teacher even though I never had classes under him. The students and some teachers unloaded their dislike of my father on me every day. For years, I sat between all the chairs, but had interesting insights from several points of view. Later in the basic military service I felt much safer :-)

Comment: @WoJ   a student trying to explain  = Some students crying and begging . Others wearing extra short skirts.

Comment: @UlrichDiez: well, that sounds tough. In France we have a reasonable system (compulsory kindergarten, 5 years of primary school, 4 years of middle school, 3 years of lyceum). You can diverge to a different school but unfortunately, we do not have a good, well-recognized equivalent of Fachschule. And then, after the end exams (Abitur) it all goes bat crazy...

Comment: @UlrichDiez ...Universities are open without exams - you can imagine the circus to get in, and the level afterward. You do not immediately get to the elite schools, you have to do 2 years of "preparation", an idiotic system where people work to death to pass an exam afterwards and not do anything anymore once they are in that top school. France hates the concept of entry exams (for mysterious reasons), which would solve all the inequalities.

Comment: @WoJ I never had to take whatsoever entry-exam during my school career. For the question of what kind of school to attend after elementary school, the report marks of the last elementary school grade and the opinion of the parents were decisive. For the question of what those who came to the Gymnasium would be allowed to study nine years later, the average grades of the final school report were decisive. In these grades, however, the results in final exams, called "Abitur," had great weight. A bad grade in such an exam could, however, be put into relation by good grades in the corresponding...

Comment: @WoJ ...corresponding subject in all class tests before this exam. (The only school exams I found really stressful were in sports. :-) ) In this way, people who had no idea about physics, for example, but had good grades in literature, could get a grade point average that allowed them to study physics at university. I still remember right after a math lecture in the second semester someone asking what that integral sign meant...